# Kafka Streams: Create source topic automatically

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm currently working on Kafka Streams, that requires pushing messages into an inbound topic (source), doing a bit of processing off the inbound topic, and then pushing the processed message to the outbound topic. My java App is consuming messages from the outbound topic.
When I run the app for the first time, I see the following error message:

```
The following source topics are missing/unknown: [local.inbound.topic]. Please make sure all source topics have been pre-created before starting the Streams application.
```

I researched this and learnt that for Kafka Streams, the inbound topic needs to be created before hand. One option is to ask an admin to create the topic before deploying my app so that Kafka Streams is ready to read from the inbound topic. The other is to create this programatically. I was wondering if there is a way to do this via Java (to create the inbound topic automatically before the Streams runner kicks in)? And also, it is wise to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create topics with the admin api of kafka like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(
  AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_CONTAINER.getBootstrapServers()
);

Admin admin = Admin.create(properties)

int partitions = 1;
short replicationFactor = 1;
NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(topicName, partitions, replicationFactor);

CreateTopicsOptions topicOptions = new CreateTopicsOptions()
  .validateOnly(true)
  .retryOnQuotaViolation(false);

CreateTopicsResult result = admin.createTopics(
  Collections.singleton(newTopic), topicOptions
);
```